# Computing the sixth derivative of $F(x) = \int_1^x\sin^3(1-t)\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Compute the sixth derivative at $x_0 = 1$ of
>   $$F(x) = \int_1^x\sin^3(1-t)\mathrm dt$$

It's from a multiple choice test. I was able to narrow down the choices to $0$ and $60$. I guessed $0$ and obviously it was the other one.

How do I compute that? The first derivative is
$$\sin^3(1 - x)$$
but after the third one it gets hellish. Is there a fast way to compute it? Maybe using some series expansion trick?

Comment: @Amzoti: Yeah, but I cannot use WolframAlpha in a test! It must surely be some faster way than actually computing it.

Comment: You have the right idea with the series. What's keeping you from pursuing it?

Comment: I'm just curious, what were the other choices and how did you dismiss them?

Comment: @BarryCipra: They were: "Does not exist, because F is not differentiable six times at $1$" and "$-\frac16$". I excluded the second one because from the first derivatives it seemed clear that it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative approach (avoiding trig identities you might not remember), given that you found the first derivative to be $\sin^3(1-x)$, let us write $t=1-x$ for now and recall the Taylor expansion:
$$ \sin^3(t) = \left[t-\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^5}{120} + O(t^7)\right]^3. $$

It is easy enough to show via dumb, direct algebra, that
$$ \sin^3(t) = \left[t-\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^5}{120} + O(t^7)\right]^3 = t^3-\frac{t^5}{2}+O(t^7). $$

Now, we take 5 derivatives, substitute $t=0$ (since that corresponds to $x=1$), and take care to multiply by $(-1)^5$, since $\partial_t=-\partial_x$:
$$ \frac{d^5}{dx^5}\sin^3(1-x)\big|_{x=1} = (-1)^5 \frac{d^5}{dt^5} \sin^3(t)\big|_{t=0} = -(-1)^5 \frac{5!}{2} + O(t^2)\big|_{t=0} = 60.$$

Comment: Nice, this is what I was expecting. I was forgetting the $(-1)^5$ part!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the trig identity
$$\cos 3u=4\cos^3 u-3\cos u$$

which leads to
$$\cos^3 u=\frac 14(\cos 3u + 3\cos u)$$

Replacing $u$ with its complement $\frac{\pi}2-u$ we get
$$\cos^3\left(\frac{\pi}2-u\right)=\frac 14\left[\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}2-3u\right) + 3\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-u\right)\right]$$
$$\sin^3 u=\frac 14(-\sin 3u + 3\sin u)$$

Substitute $u=1-x$ and this will be much easier to differentiate five times.

(I got the initial identity from the [third Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind) which is fairly well known. The final identity can also be derived by using the sine addition formula twice and replacing $\cos^2 x$ with $1-\sin^2 x$.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray*} F(x) &=& -\int_{0}^{1-x}\sin^3 t\,dt =\int_{0}^{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{4}\sin(3t)-\frac{3}{4}\sin t\right)\,dt\\&=&-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}\cos(x-1)-\frac{1}{12}\cos(3(x-1))\end{eqnarray*}$$
so:
$$ F^{(6)}(x)=-\frac{3}{4}\cos(x-1)+\frac{3^6}{12}\cos(3(x-1)) $$
and:
$$ F^{(6)}(1) = -\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3^5}{4} = \frac{240}{4} = \color{red}{60}.$$

Comment: Where did you get that identity for $\sin^3 t$ in your first line? I did not know it and had to figure it out (as in my answer). Is that identity commonly known?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: it comes from the sine triplication formula or from $T_3(x)$ as you pointed out.

Comment: Nice, but there is no way that I'll remember that identity!

Answer (score 0):

the write answser is 60.  In order to compute the derivative you can use the exponential form of the sinus. According to my computation the sixth derivative is

\begin{equation}
\frac{3}{4}(3^4 cos(3(1-x))- cos(1-x))
\end{equation}